# Magento 2.3 TinyMCE V5

Tags: magento2.3, tinymce

Need to use latest version of TinyMCE V5 with Magento V2.3.

I tried to update tinymce js to latest version but its doesn't works at all after update. What are steps are required to integrated TinyMCE V5.

Is there any module available for it?

Comment: Have you seen the rather incomplete page https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/wysiwyg/configure-tinymce-editor.html ?

Comment: Yes.. But that doesn't provides any reference for updating Tiny MCE to latest version.